# background cover and z-index issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a div `.header-content`, with the content of the website on top of another div `.header-bg`, with just a background cover and a height using `z-index`.

If I change the `.header-bg` to `position:absolute`, the background image disappear, but the `.header-content` is positioned in the right place. If I change it to `position: relative`, the background appear, but the content is positioned after the background image, not on top of it.

Does anyone have had the same problem?

The HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="header header-bg"></div>
        <div class="header home-header">

            <div class="header-content">
                <a href="#" class="logo txtimg" title="Back to Homepage">LOGO</a>
                <p class="slogan">SLOGAN</p>
            </div>

            <div class="header slider">
                <div class="slider-navbar">
                </div>
            </div>

            <navbar class="menu home-menu">
                test
            </navbar>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The CSS

```
.logo{
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat;
    height: 96px;
    width: 402px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.slogan {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/*.css-img-replacement*/
.txtimg {
    text-indent: -9999em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-bg{
    background: #bf1718 url(img/header_bg.png) no-repeat 50% !important;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:0;
    position: relative;
}

.header {
    height:588px;
}

.header-content {
    padding: 1em 0;
    z-index: 900;
    position: absolute;
}
```

(Sorry if I've made some English mistakes, I'm French, hope you'll understand anyway)

Comment: Try this: .header-bg{position:absolute; width:100%; height:252px}

Comment: what exactly you wanna do? can you share a picture?

Comment: Are you going to do like this ? [https://jsfiddle.net/qe0pqcea/](https://jsfiddle.net/qe0pqcea/)

Comment: I think you need like: http://jsfiddle.net/6d0tbvwc/

Answer (score 2):

You should give the `.header-content` a value for it's top position :

```
.header-content {
    padding: 1em 0;
    z-index: 900;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

An absolute element will keep its static position when no value for top, right, bottom or left positioning is added. The static position is the position the element would have in the flow of the page when the `position` property isn't specified any further.

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the answers!

I've just add a width:100% to my .header-bg, and put my .header-bg and .home-header to position:relative and it worked fine!